# A problem showing the data in the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, many-to-many

This code works with no errors but it deosn't show the '`{{skill.skillName}}`' in the template 
so what is the problem?

this is the result when I try to print `skills` from the views

```
<QuerySet [<Skill: nope>, <Skill: yep>, <Skill: yes>]>
```

models.py

```
class User_Model(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phoneNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/', default='users/user-man1.jpg')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Skill(models.Model):
    skillName = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skillName
```

views.py

```
def memberOnlyDetail(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    skills = Skill.objects.filter(user=user)
    memberDetails =User_Model.objects.get(user=user)

    return render(request, 'memberMemberProfilePage.html', {'memberDetails': memberDetails}, {'skills': skills})
    enter code here
```

memberMemberProfilePage.html

```
{%for skill in skills%}
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 hvr-grow-rotate">
    <p>{{skill1.skillName}}</p>
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: `{{skill1.skillName}}` should be `{{skill.skillName}}`.

Comment: I fixed it but still doesn't work @FynnBecker

Comment: I edited the post .. Can you check it again maybe you will find the problem @FynnBecker

Comment: sanity check... does the user that you are testing this on have skills

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the `render()` function.

> Here's the signature from the [django
>   documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):
>
> ```
> render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
> ```

Now let's look at the arguments you are passing:

```
render(request, 'memberMemberProfilePage.html', {'memberDetails': memberDetails}, {'skills': skills})
```

While you are correctly passing the `request`, `template_name` and `{'memberDetails': memberDetails}` as `context`, you pass `{'skills': skills}` as the fourth argument i.e. as `content_type`.

---

To correctly pass `skills` in your context just include it in your context dictionary like so:

```
def memberOnlyDetail(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    skills = Skill.objects.filter(user=user)
    memberDetails =User_Model.objects.get(user=user)

    return render(request, 'memberMemberProfilePage.html', {'memberDetails': memberDetails, 'skills': skills})
```

Comment: Omg that is a stupid mistake :"D thanx alot @FynnBecker